# ''We average 8 hours’ work a day.'' Is this a correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

"We average 8 hours’ work a day." Is this sentence correct? 
This is just a sentence written from my friend and I'd like to know the usage and form of the word, "average")

Please give me some examples to explain the usage.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/average_3

Comment: Please check a good dictionary first. If still in doubt, try asking on [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Kris, thanks. I've check online dictionaries already but couldn't make sure if this sentence written from my friend is correct. Therefore, I posted it here to find people to help debug the sentence!^^

Comment: Have you found it on the link now?

Comment: Uh, I still feel a little bit confused. Could you help explain this for me? Thanks!

Comment: *Average* is also a verb. ibid. *Drivers in London can expect to average about 12 miles per hour* (= to have that as their average speed). HTH.

Comment: So, "We average 8 hours’ work a day." also means "On average, we work 8 hours per day.", right?

Comment: Yes, and the sentence "We average 8 hours’ work a day." is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you're worried about the apostrophe usage. N1's N2 is often used to signify 'N2 is associated with N1' (Traveller's Check; Dogs' Home; three hours' work) as well as 'N2 is the property / a part of N1' (Tom's arm; Tom's watch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already got the answer, here's some more information which would be useful.

Take a look at [this definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/average_3) of "average" as a verb from the Cambridge Dictionaries-

> **average**
>   *verb*: to reach a particular amount as an average

Examples given in the link include-

> Enquiries to our office average 1,000 calls a month

and

> Many doctors average (= work an average of) 70 hours a week

and

> Trainee accountants average (= earn an average of) £12,000 per year

If you look at the second example given here, you'll see that the sentence you have in mind-

> We average 8 hours’ work a day

is perfectly all right.

Comment: This is a really helpful information for me. =D

Comment: Most people average 168 hours a week.

Answer (score 0):

"We average 8 hours’ work a day" and "On average, we work 8 hours per day," are both correct.

A similar example:

> We average an hour's travel a day (On average, we travel an hour a
>   day)

Comment: Great! Now my question is well solved. Thank you~

Comment: Not a problem, @Sandra.  Forum guidelines specify that one shouldn't make off-topic discussions but I have to express my appreciation for the fact that you have taken the time to thank every single person who responded to your post! It is reassuring to know that being nice is still going strong in this world. Wish you the best.

Comment: Wish you the best as well. Romulus.

Answer (score -2):

**We average 8 hours’ work a day.**

Simply say ''we work 8 hours daily on average''

Your friend's sentence is okay but the order is completely wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the word order of "We average 8 hours’ work a day." where average is a verb.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is nothing wrong with “We average eight hours’ work a day”.

Comment: Hi Janus, do you mean Daniel's answer?
Correct answers: 
1) We average eight hours’ work a day.
2) We work 8 hours daily on average.
3) On average, we work 8 hours per day.

Comment: Yes, I mean Daniel’s answer. His was the only answer there was at the time, and it is the answer the comment was written under.

Comment: I see. Now I think my question is well solved.